# MSB4062 in Visual Studio 2017 while Compiling a starter Visual C++ project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following build error while compiling my project. The whole error can be seen below

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(181,5): error MSB4062: The "GetOutOfDateItems" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask
```

This error happens every time I start building the project(even the basic Visual C++ project on VS2017). Please help !